# Issue with associative arrays in awk

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, associative-array

I am trying to use a associative array in bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A animals
animals["moo"]="cow"

animals["woof"]="dog"
awk '/INfO/{animals["meow"]="cat";print $3;}' logs/animals.log

echo ${#animals[@]}
for i in "${!animals[@]}"
do
echo "key  : $i"
done
```

In the output I don't see the `meow` getting added into `animals` array. But `print $3` works fine. It prints `cat`.

Here is the output:

```
cat
2
key  : moo
key  : woof
```

Comment: awk is creating a totally independent array `animals` which has nothing to do with BASH associative array of the same name.

Comment: Is there any way to link it with my bash array.

Comment: why? use one language or the other. Else store a generic fmt array definition in a text file, and then process as needed to work in both awk and bash. Good luck.

Comment: No you cannot do that without some patchy/hackish code. Better not to mix variable space of 2 different tools.

Comment: Thanks . I will stick to awk.

Comment: I agree with the idea not to mix variable space of 2 tools, but c'mon, bash/awk .... patchy/hachish code is the norm! ;-) Glad the OP will only be using one. Good luck to all.